# Rxjs plus minus button with min max and not negative values

Tags: rxjs5

How to avoid negative value ?

I've tried with filter but

if the value becomes negative

you should click twice to get

it positive.

```
const start = 0;
    const min = 0;
    const max = 3
    var plus$ =  Observable.fromEvent(this.getNativeElement(this.btnPlus), 'click');
    var minus$ =  Observable.fromEvent(this.getNativeElement(this.btnMinus), 'click');
    var plusOrMinus$ = Observable.merge(plus$.mapTo(1), minus$.mapTo(-1));
    plusOrMinus$
    .scan((acc,curr) => acc+curr, start)
    .filter(x => x > min)
    .subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

and if I wanted add a max value ?

UPDATE

This do the work for min
it's a little messy ^^

```
const start = 0;
    const min = 0;
    const max = 3
    const plus$ =  Observable.fromEvent(this.getNativeElement(this.btnPlus), 'click');
    const minus$ =  Observable.fromEvent(this.getNativeElement(this.btnMinus), 'click');
    const plusOrMinus$ = Observable.merge(plus$.mapTo(1), minus$.mapTo(-1));
    plusOrMinus$
    .scan((acc,curr) =>{
      if(acc === start){
        if(curr > 0){
          return acc+curr;
        }
      }
      if(acc > start){
        return acc+curr;
      }
      else{
        throw new Error('0 value');
      }
    },
    start)
    .catch((e,obs)=> obs.startWith(0))
    .subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

Comment: Why not add a `.map(x => Math.max(0, x))` to ensure your value does not go below 0?

Comment: because of if you click more times on minus and than in plus the value in acc is still negative (the same of filter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand your question correctly you want to prevent your inputs (+1/-1) from letting the total go out of bound (min, max). To do so you can use `Math.min(nextVal, max)` and `Math.max(nextVal, min)`. Combined you will end up with `Math.max(Math.min(nextVal, max), min)`. Next is using this in your `.scan()` function.

```js
const incStream = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(document.getElementById('button_inc'), 'click').mapTo(1);
const decStream = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(document.getElementById('button_dec'), 'click').mapTo(-1);

const min = 0;
const max = 3;

Rx.Observable.merge(incStream, decStream)
  .scan((acc, curr) => Math.max(Math.min(acc + curr, max), min), 0)
  .startWith(0)
  .distinctUntilChanged()
  .subscribe(val => document.getElementById('result').value = val);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.0.3/Rx.js"></script>
  <input type='button' value='+1' id='button_inc' />
  <input type='button' value='-1' id='button_dec' />
  <input type='text' id='result' />
```

The `.startWith(0)` is used to have a 0 value emitted to the stream before your first scan value arrives. `.distinctUntilChanged()` is used to not update the result with the same value (for instance when reaching `max` when using +1 multiple times).